# What is this gcc compiler option? (-lGL -lGLU -lglut)

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, compiler-options

I am developing GTK program in C and I have a makefile that I am stuck what this compiler option this is.
[image: gcc compiler options in makefile]

Any ideas? 
I am sorry this is a question style, but I am really stuck.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text; post the text as 'code' in the question.

Answer (score 3):

`-l` flags are used to link libraries to your application needed for whatever project you're working on. In your case, the `-l` flags are used to link the OpenGL Library Toolkit.

See: http://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/gcc/gcc-l.htm